# Internal Memory does not show up in the Computer(file Explorer)

Tags: samsung, internal-storage, samsung-galaxy-grand

I have Samsung GT-I19082 Galaxy Grand duos. When I connect it to my computer, it does not show the internal memory nor sdcard memory. When I switch to Camera memory option in the Phone, internal memory shows up in the PC, but it does not let me transfer data.

What can I do?

Comment: I have tried installing Samsung Kies to the computer, but no luck.

Comment: I have installed custom ROM on the device, its CM 12.1 which is based on Android 5.0.1. I see options like Media, Camera, Charge Only and SD Card. I have tried all of them. Only Camera is able to show the Internal memory into  the computer that too without an effective data transfers possible.

Comment: Which particular build of CyanogenMod are you using? Is it nightly or a stable one?

Comment: Exactly this one. http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-grand-duos/development/rom-glade-rom-t3057502

Answer (score 0):

First ensure you have a good connection between phone and PC.  After you have connected,  unlock your phone and open the status bar.  There you should have a notification that reads "**USB for charging**" select it.  A dialog will pop up giving you a list of options.  Select the option "**File transfers**"  With this option selected you should be able to see "**Internal storage**" on your PC.

Comment: In the Dialog Box, I see options like Media Transfer, Camera, Charge Only and SD Card. I have tried all of them. :-(

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I chose MTP option to view Internal Storage.